# New reviewer failed for finding the duplicate

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I was failed for adding a Q comment to a test review question (same question pretending to be from a joiner) along the lines of "This is a cut'n'paste duplicate of XXX" with a link to a hot question from last week. Apparently this counts as lax negativity rather than good observation along with a precise link.

It feels like a trap for new reviewers. What is the advice next time I recognise something? Check it's the same, assume it's a test and tell SO what it wants to hear?

(This is almost as annoying as not being told up front that downvoting answers costs rep when the review system encourages you to vote on them!)

Comment: The reputation cost for downvoting answers _is_ explained when you read about the [downvote privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) linked from your user page.

Comment: If it's an exact duplicate, then why not flag/vote to close as duplicate instead of commenting?

Comment: @BDL I don't have any "close as dup" priv yet (new reviewer!) Nor would that have passed the test :)

Comment: @drekbour: You can't close vote. But you can flag as duplicate. I agree that not passing the test is still a problem.